# How to delete the 3rd occurrence of a pattern in a file, and beyond

Tags: regex, sed, awk, text-editing

How can I find the third occurrence of a pattern in a file (Note: not in a line) and delete the line containing the pattern and *n* lines below that (say, 5 lines below).

e.g.,

```
COVER
fafjasfj
isfapifj
ajfsdaijf
COVER
oaijfeiahf
aasdf
fafadf
df
This is a COVER                                             *
efjafa                                                      *
aifaidfj                                                    *
aifhaidfh                                                   *
idfhaifh                                                    *
aidfhiadhf                                                  *
aifhaifh
iafaishf
jgsjg
fbsfgbf
```

I want to delete the complete line containing the third occurrence of the pattern `COVER` and the five lines below that. These lines are indicated with `*`s. (Note: the `*`s are not part of the file.

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you're asking.  Are you looking for the 3rd occurrence of any text or text that you specify somewhere?  Is it always 5 lines or is that a variable?

Comment: I would like to delete the 3rd occurrence of a particular text and few lines below that , that 5 is a variable as

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '$1=="COVER"{l++}l==3{l2++} l!=3 || l2>6' file
COVER
fafjasfj
isfapifj
ajfsdaijf
COVER
oaijfeiahf
aasdf
fafadf
df
aifhaifh
iafaishf
jgsjg
fbsfgbf
```

The last `{print}` statement is not necessary because by default, `awk` print current line on a true condition.